# How to get the field name in Params::Validate in Perl

Tags: perl, validation, parameters

```
validate(
    @_,
    {
        foo => {
            callbacks => {
                'smaller than a breadbox' => sub { shift() < $breadbox },
                'green or blue'           => sub {
                    return 1 if $_[0] eq 'green' || $_[0] eq 'blue';
                    &$failed(‘**fieldname** value is Invalid’);
                }
        bar => {
            callbacks => {
                'yellow or red'           => sub {
                    return 1 if $_[0] eq 'yellow ' || $_[0] eq 'red';
                    &$failed(‘**fieldname** value is Invalid’);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

`Params::Validate` - In the above code if my validation fails, I am calling the subroutine failed in which I am displaying the error message. I want to get field name from callbacks in params validate for which the validation has failed instead of directly passing the field name in the failed subroutine. Here foo and bar are fieldnames. How can I get the field name?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Params::Validate;

my %template =
(
    bar => {
        'color correct' => sub {
            my ($fieldname, $value) = @_[0..1];
            return 1 if $value eq 'green' || $value eq 'blue';
            failed("'$fieldname': value '$value' is invalid");
        }
    }, 
    foo => {
        'smaller than a breadbox' => sub {
           my ($fieldname, $value) = @_[0..1];
           return 1 if $value < 20; 
           failed("'$fieldname' value '$value' is invalid");
        }
    }
);

func( bar => 'green', foo =>  14 );
func( bar => 'yellow', foo =>  17 );

sub func {
    my %validate = map { $_ => { callbacks => get_callbacks( $_, $template{$_} ) } }
      keys %template;

    validate( @_, \%validate );
}

sub get_callbacks {
    my ( $fname, $callbacks ) = @_;

    my %cb;

    for my $name (keys %$callbacks ) {
        $cb{$name} = sub { 
           my $fieldname = $fname; 
           $callbacks->{$name}->( $fieldname, @_ ) 
        };
    }
    return \%cb;
}

sub failed {
    die $_[0];
}
```

Note: this uses closures to define a persistent fieldname variable. See [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for more information.

Comment: ok it was just an example. could you clarify your question maybe?

Comment: There are multiple fields, if one field is there than this will work